# Filtering GCS uris before job execution

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a frequent use case I couldn't solve.
Let's say I have a filepattern like `gs://mybucket/mydata/*/files.json` where * is supposed to match a date.

Imagine I want to keep 251 dates (this is an example, let's say a big number of dates but without a meta-pattern to match them like 2019* or else).
For now, I have two options :

- create a TextIO for every single file, which is overkill and fails almost everytime (graph too large)
- read ALL data and then filter it within my job from data : which is also overkill when you have 10 TB of data while you only need 10 Gb for instance

In my case, I would like to just do something like that (pseudo code) :

```
Read(LIST[uri1,uri2,...,uri251])
```

And that this instruction actually spawn a single TextIO task on the graph. 
I am sorry if I missed something, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it, the naming was mileading me :

```
Example 2: reading a PCollection of filenames.

 Pipeline p = ...;

 // E.g. the filenames might be computed from other data in the pipeline, or
 // read from a data source.
 PCollection<String> filenames = ...;

 // Read all files in the collection.
 PCollection<String> lines =
     filenames
         .apply(FileIO.matchAll())
         .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
         .apply(TextIO.readFiles());
```

(Quoted from Apache Beam documentation https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html)

So we need to generate a PCollection of URIS (with `Create/of`) or to read it from the pipeline, then to match all the uris (or patterns I guess) and the to read all files.